# What is the basic difference between Naive and Optimal Bayes classifier?

Tags: bayesian, references

What is the basic difference between Naive and Optimal Bayes classifier?

What can an Optimal Bayes Classifier do which a Naive Bayes Classifier can't?

Comment: Please add a reference or otherwise clarify (the answer seems to be about optimal Bayes classifiers, but it is not clear whether "Optimal Bayes algorithm" refers to that or something else).

Answer (score 4):

When you know the actual data distribution $p(X,Y)$ exactly with $(X,Y)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d \times {1,\dots,K}$, where $x$ is the data and $y$ is the label, the optimal Bayes classifier works as: 
$$C(x) = argmax_{y' \in {1,\dots,K}} p(Y=y'|X=x)$$

This minimizes the probability of error. Think of an arbitrary classification rule $R(x)$ mapping $x$ to a label $y$:

$$p(Error) = \int p(x)(1-p(R(x)|x))dx$$
$$p(Error) = \int p(x)dx -\int p(x)p(R(x)|x)dx$$
$$p(Error) = 1 -\mathbb{E}[p(R(x)|x)]$$

It is clear that $\mathbb{E}[p(R(x)|x)]$ will be largest when $R(x)=C(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand this formal notation.

Comment: @yahoo.com what exactly you don't understand about the answer? Your question is vague, so you got pretty general answer. The notation is pretty standard, so it would be hard to guess what is that you don't understand and what you want to know.